# Set EF6 Code First strings fluently to nvarchar(max)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I'm building an EF6 code first model using the fluent API. My understanding is, by default, strings will be `nvarchar(max)`, which (to be blunt) is dumb for a default. So I added the following convention code to set max default length to 255 characters:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
    .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(255));
```

Then I created a decorator like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class TextAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

I want to apply this to specific string properties that I actually want to be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

What do I put in the fluent API to make sure all string properties with the `[Text]` decorator are built in the database with `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?  I assume it would be something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
    .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(a => typeof(TextAttribute).IsAssignableFrom(a.AttributeType)))
    .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(?????));
```

Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: Is using the actual nvarchar(max) length limit wrong? 2^30-1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't know if you've found an answer by now, but in case anyone else is wondering how to do it, simply set the SQL datatype and ignore the HasMaxLength() invocation.

```
        modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
            .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(a => typeof(TextAttribute).IsAssignableFrom(a.AttributeType)))
            .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)"));
```

Using IsMaxLength() or HasMaxLength(null) would set the field to nvarchar(4000) (varchar(8000) if specifying the data type as varchar).

Answer (score 17):

If you're doing it inside an `EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>` class, it is similar to @RickNo's answer, but is done like this:

```
Property(x => x.MyVarcharMaxProperty)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a method to indicate that you use the maximum allowed by the database.

IsMaxLength ()

```
    modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
        .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(a => typeof(TextAttribute).IsAssignableFrom(a.AttributeType)))
        .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("nvarchar").IsMaxLength());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use HasColumnType

[image]

or you can use without any HasColumnType or HasMaxLength.
There is no need to use **HasMaxLength**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It works for me in EF Core 7

```
entity.Property(e => e.ColumnName)
    .HasMaxLength(int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: Your example is for VARCHAR(MAX). For NVARCHAR(MAX) you need to combine with .IsUnicode(true). See my answer with the details.

Answer (score 1):

If you use other database provider than `MS SQL Server` then column type is possible to be other than `NVARCHAR` and for this you need to use `HasMaxLength` combine with `IsUnicode`.

If you use:

```
builder.Property(e => e.ColumnName)
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
```

This is hard-coded for `MS SQL Server` database provider and if you want to switch to other provider in time, you need to change all your entities configuration and also to change the migrations.

For example PostgreSql: [PostgreSQL equivalent to SQL Server NVARCHAR (MAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521515/postgresql-equivalent-to-sql-server-nvarchar-max) or [Whats SQL Server NVARCHAR(max) equivalent in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98268/whats-sql-server-nvarcharmax-equivalent-in-mysql)

You can use for `NVARCHAR(MAX)`:

```
builder.Property(e => e.ColumnName)
    .HasMaxLength(int.MaxValue)
    .IsUnicode(true);
```

You can use for `VARCHAR(MAX)`:

```
builder.Property(e => e.ColumnName)
    .HasMaxLength(int.MaxValue)
    .IsUnicode(false);
```