# PostgreSQL equivalent to SQL Server NVARCHAR (MAX)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that in PostgreSQL, `VARCHAR(n)` is equivalent to SQL Server's `NVARCHAR(n)`, but how can I use something like `VARCHAR(MAX)` in PostgreSQL, something similar to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in SQL Server?

Comment: `text`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html

Comment: @Abelisto Please answer the question so that I can accept.

Comment: It is too short for the answer. Just read PostgreSQL documentation carefully - IMO it is really nice reading :)

Comment: @Abelisto True, but I wish if you provide here in answer so that it can be helpful for someone else in future.

Comment: It's **`NVARCHAR`** - not **`NVCHAR`** - in SQL Server  - corrrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PostgreSQL for `char(n)` and `varchar(n)` it is just limited by `n` argument (not sure about nature of such limitation, it seems that it is 20 Mb or 10M of 2-bytes characters or something):

```
postgres=# select 'a'::varchar(999999999);
ERROR:  length for type varchar cannot exceed 10485760
```

So if you really need the equivalent for MS SQL Server `nvarchar(max)` - it could be `varchar(10485760)`

However to use really unlimited character values there are two ways: `varchar` or `character varying` without argument or just `text` type. Read more in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) and note about Tip provided in it:

> There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text or character varying should be used instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to created an "unbounded" `varchar` column just use `varchar` without a length restriction.

[From the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html)

> If character varying is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size

So you can use:

```
create table foo
( 
  unlimited  varchar
);
```

Another alternative is to use `text`:

```
create table foo
( 
  unlimited text
);
```

More details about character data types are in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

Answer (score 0):

**text, varchar** can be used for this requirement. i used **varchar**

**Character Types   Description**

character varying(n), varchar(n)    --- variable-length with limit

character(n), char(n)   -- fixed-length, blank padded

**text, varchar**   -- variable unlimited length

More Details:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-char-varchar-text/